# AWS Glue Job is returning error while enabling the job boomark as ON

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

We have a requirement to convert the existing S3 source files, Which are currently in JSON format to Parquet , Below are the steps taken to achieve the same .

1)Created GLUE job named "RawEventsToParquet" , Which will read the data from 'raw_events' (which is a table currently existing with source as S3 JSON 
files) and formats  the data to Parquet and stores into new S3 bucket "S3/prepared/events" .
2)Created a crawler "crawlParquetPreparedFiles" which crawl through above said S3 bucket and creates a catalogue "prepared_events" and table "prepared_highbond_events".
3)We can query Athena and read the data from prepared_events .

We also want the JOB to just create the Parquet files for the new S3 JSON files and should not duplicate and load the already processed files , Hence after researching found an option to enable the advance property Job bookmark .It runs fine in the first run and was able to query the data from Parquet files created , However in the second run , Ideally it should not create any parquet files as we do not have any new files added in the source S3 , But the job fails with below error . I am new to AWS so I am finding it difficult to fix this , Help is very much appreciated . Thanks in advance .

**AnalysisException: '\nDatasource does not support writing empty or nested empty schemas.\nPlease make sure the data schema has at least one or more column(s).\n ;'**

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "raw_events", table_name = "highbond_events", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "raw_events", table_name = "highbond_events", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mapping = [("anonymousid", "string", "anonymousid", "string"), ("channel", "string", "channel", "string"), ("context", "struct", "context", "struct"), ("event", "string", "event", "string"), ("integrations", "string", "integrations", "string"), ("messageid", "string", "messageid", "string"), ("originaltimestamp", "string", "originaltimestamp", "string"), ("projectid", "string", "projectid", "string"), ("properties", "struct", "properties", "struct"), ("receivedat", "string", "receivedat", "string"), ("sentat", "string", "sentat", "string"), ("timestamp", "string", "timestamp", "string"), ("type", "string", "type", "string"), ("userid", "string", "userid", "string"), ("version", "int", "version", "int"), ("writekey", "string", "writekey", "string"), ("_metadata", "struct", "_metadata", "struct"), ("category", "string", "category", "string"), ("name", "string", "name", "string"), ("traits", "struct", "traits", "struct"), ("groupid", "string", "groupid", "string"), ("year", "string", "year", "string"), ("month", "string", "month", "string"), ("day", "string", "day", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]
## @return: applymapping1
## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("anonymousid", "string", "anonymousid", "string"), ("channel", "string", "channel", "string"), ("context", "struct", "context", "struct"), ("event", "string", "event", "string"), ("integrations", "string", "integrations", "string"), ("messageid", "string", "messageid", "string"), ("originaltimestamp", "string", "originaltimestamp", "string"), ("projectid", "string", "projectid", "string"), ("properties", "struct", "properties", "struct"), ("receivedat", "string", "receivedat", "string"), ("sentat", "string", "sentat", "string"), ("timestamp", "string", "timestamp", "string"), ("type", "string", "type", "string"), ("userid", "string", "userid", "string"), ("version", "int", "version", "int"), ("writekey", "string", "writekey", "string"), ("_metadata", "struct", "_metadata", "struct"), ("category", "string", "category", "string"), ("name", "string", "name", "string"), ("traits", "struct", "traits", "struct"), ("groupid", "string", "groupid", "string"), ("year", "string", "year", "string"), ("month", "string", "month", "string"), ("day", "string", "day", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
## @type: ResolveChoice
## @args: [choice = "make_struct", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2"]
## @return: resolvechoice2
## @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]
resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping1, choice = "make_struct", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")
## @type: DropNullFields
## @args: [transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3"]
## @return: dropnullfields3
## @inputs: [frame = resolvechoice2]
dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")
## @type: DataSink
## @args: [connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://acl-playground-grc-cleansed-data/prepared/events"}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "datasink4"]
## @return: datasink4
## @inputs: [frame = dropnullfields3]
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dropnullfields3, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://acl-playground-grc-cleansed-data/prepared/events"}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
job.commit()
```

Comment: Can you confirm if there is any data in dynamic frame when you are running the job for second time? I think there might be no new data present when you have enabled bookmarking and also how are you writing the data?

Comment: Firstly I thanks for responding and helping . Anwer for your comment is for the next run, no new files were loaded to the source S3 bucket  and yes your assumtion is correct here . I am not sure I completely understood your question "how you are writing the data" ,   I assume you are asking about the Target here and the target is again S3 bucket with file saved as Parquet format where as source is also an S3 bucket but with JSON files .

Comment: Can you update your post with script that you have used?

Comment: Sure , Let me do that .

Comment: I have posted the script .

Comment: Update : For second time when I have updated couple of source files and loaded back again to S3 source bucket , I was able to process only those modified files , This shows that Glue job bookmark works the way it should to load only delta reords , Now the only concern I have is when the Job is scheduled and runs with no new files in the source bucket , Then the Job throws error which I described in my post, Which somehow is a false alarm . If I am able to handle the error then all is fine . Big thanks to bdcloud :)

Comment: can you try removing resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping1, choice = "make_struct", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")
 from your code? Just pass on applymapping1 to next  transformation dropnullfields3 and re-run this?

Comment: Sure, let me do that and share the results here, It will take some time though(11 am IST), We cannot access AWS outside of our office network:). Thanks again.

Comment: I tried taking out resolvechoice2 and as well as drop null fields, But still the Job is failing with the same error , And as well as is there a way to dynamically get the columns , The thing is if there are few columns added to the source files down the line how would the job behave?  WIll it going to automatically create new columns or is it going to break, Thanks in advance .

Comment: I am facing a challenge on this. To do load testing against the Glue job, we have genrated files and saved it in  S3, ideally now the JOB should pick up these newly added files and process as the modified/created date is new and JOB is not aware of these files, but it fails to prcoess these files and error out with  "AnalysisException: '\nDatasource does not support writing empty or nested empty schemas.\nPlease make sure the data schema has at least one or more column(s).\n ;'"